# External View activated but syntax error persists

Tags: abap, hana

I have an External View from SAP HANA on my SAP ECC system, it's all OK on application servers DEV and QAS, but in PRD I have the error *"The type 'XXXX' is unknown."* for this line:

```
DATA: t_table type XXXX.
```

In PRD, if I go to SE11 and display XXXX, it's all activated with no errors. But I can't do DATA Preview (Authorization Error).

I have other External Views on this system, and it works (SOURCE, DATA PREVIEW, etc).

I already transported a fresh request with objects.

Comment: Send the screenshots from SE11 for your XXXX type both from DEV and PRD system. Moreover attach the System status screenshots of those both systems (System status dialog is where you see what database the SAP is on).

Comment: It's a customer system, so it's dificult to access production.... I'll try get more information, and try run an authorization trace. Thank you.

Comment: Did you check the information/warning messages in the transport-to-PRD log for this view? Note: the External View is shown as "Active" but maybe it's not (an existing case of false-active views is for CDS views as explained in note [2421686 - CDS view(DDL SQL View) cannot be activated with RUTDDLSACT](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/2421686)).

Comment: Sorry for the delay, it was difficult to customer release the access to the system, but what I managed to do and it worked was to do a RESYNC of External View. Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

With the limited amount of information in this question all one can do is *guess* what the problem might be.

My **guess** is: on your PRD (production) system, the `_SYS_REPO` user does not have the necessary `SELECT`-privilege `WITH GRANT OPTION` but *just* the `SELECT`-privilege. That means, the activation can be performed by `_SYS_REPO` but it cannot grant a `SELECT` privilege on the activated views back to the `SAP<SID>`/SAP schema owner user.

If this is the problem the solution is simple: grant the necessary `SELECT ... WITH GRANT OPTION` to `_SYS_REPO` and re-activate the transported objects.

Comment: But others External Views is working fine.... Why just one need Authorizarion? What information you need?

Comment: The information you need is which privilege is missing. You can find that out by creating an authorization trace.